# Select all rows where a varchar column converts to a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a `varchar` column that has generally has a decimal value, but some times there is some garbage text characters in that field.

**Is it possible to filter in the `WHERE` clause for rows that sucessfully convert to a decimal value?**

I am using sql-server 2005

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function:

```
select * from YourTable where ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1
```

There's one gotcha: `isnumeric` returns 1 whenever a string can be converted to any numeric type, including `money`.  For example, say you have rows using varying decimal separators, like `7.9` and `7,9`.  Both will convert to `money`, and `isnumeric` returns 1 for both of them.  But only one converts to `decimal`, depending on the SQL Server language settings.

Comment: If the field can contain garbage remember that ISNUMERIC will tell you a currency symbol, tab, new-line, + and - is numeric.